# How to set a default parameter in Vue resource

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I am using token authentication with ajax requests and want to accompany each ajax request with 'api_token' : 'XYXYXYXYXY'.
Is there a way to set it globally in Vue resource to avoid having to add it to the payload or query parameter for each request ?

Comment: https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md#interceptors

Comment: Thanks Bert! much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found it in the documentation thanks to Bert.

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function(request, next) {
    request.params['api_token'] = 'XYXYXYXYXYXYXYXY';
    next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. It would help if you can add where this code should be added.